# Vue Router <router-link> with custom attribute + slot template not routing on frontend (SPA)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, primevue

I'm not sure any of this really matters, but I am using Nuxt3/Vue3 with Primefaces/PrimeVue UI framework, and specifically struggling with the `<Menubar>` `#item` template slot.

The gist of the situation is that in the template code that renders the menu buttons, I have this code:

```
<router-link v-slot="routerProps" :to="item.route" custom>
    <a :href="routerProps.href" v-bind="props.action">
        <span v-bind="props.icon" />
        <span v-bind="props.label">{{ label }}</span>
    </a>
</router-link>
```

The above results in everything looking perfect, but when the menu buttons are clicked, the browser treats it like an external link, sends a GET request for the specified route, then rebuilds the page from scratch which causes the entire application to be "rebooted". This is obviously not what I want in my SPA app.

I'm not using any SSR stuff (if it matters).

I have tried using `<NuxtLink>` instead of `<router-link>` and get the same behavior.

I have tried removing the `<a>` tag from the internal HTML (leaving the `<span>` tags) and this "works" as far as the the routing is concerned, but then the `<Menubar>` element is not rendered correctly and looks broken.

Removing the `custom` attribute and inner HTML of the nuxt/router link element also "works" but does not look correct on the render.

The only way I have been able to get this to work from both a visual and routing perspective was to replace the inner `<a>` tag with either a `<router-link>` or `<NuxtLink>` element, however this causes some crazy vuejs core errors if this componenent is ever unloaded for any reason during the `beforeUnmount` lifecycle hook. So this is obviously not the correct solution.

Am I missing something? Or is this an issue that needs to be resolved by the PrimeVue component author?

EDIT:
Per @KaiKai's answer and the vue docs, the missing key was adding `@click="routerProps.navigate"` to the `<a>` tag.

Final working code:

```
<router-link v-slot="routerProps" :to="item.route" custom>
    <a :href="routerProps.href" v-bind="props.action" @click="routerProps.navigate">
        <span v-bind="props.icon" />
        <span v-bind="props.label">{{ label }}</span>
    </a>
</router-link>
```

Comment: I actually do need the slot + a tag here because the component slot this exists within does not get the correct DOM that it expects if you do not write it this way. It turns out I needed to add `@click="routerProps.navigate"` to the internal a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slot props of `<RouterLink>`. ([docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/extending-router-link.html))

```js
<router-link v-slot="routerProps" :to="item.route" custom>
  <a
    :href="routerProps.href"
    v-bind="props.action"
    @click="routerProps.navigate"
  >
    <span v-bind="props.icon" />
    <span v-bind="props.label">{{ label }}</span>
  </a>
</router-link>
```

If you're using Nuxt, replacing `router-link` with `nuxt-link` is better.

Comment: @KaiKai - Thanks I did finally figure this out prior to checking back here, which is that I needed to add `@click="routerProps.navigate"` to the `<a>` tag -- I didn't need to wrap it in a closure (I'm not sure why you did when even the docs you linked do not). I'm somewhat surprised I had to do this manually, I would have assumed that `v-bind="props.action"` would have done this form me but I guess not.

Comment: @RickKukiela You can view [the implement of `<RouterLink>`](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/5c75d3a966dafaf9fce069021d872391c854296d/packages/router/src/RouterLink.ts#L234C15-L234C15). `<RouterLink custom>` directly show default slot but `<RouterLink :custom="false">` wrapped `<a @click="link.navigate" ...>`. As for the closure, it's my mistake, edit